# Can I speed this up?

Tags: php, mysql

I am concerned about speed since the do loop may have to run 15-20 times. During each loop I search and replace a few times, and select from a mysql table once each time. I just want it to be as fast as I can make it.

```
$text = file_get_contents('texts/phir-mohabbat.txt');
preg_match_all('/\S+@/', $text, $words);
preg_match_all('/@\S+/', $text, $lexs);

$count = count($words[0]);
$i = 0;
do {
  $bad = array('@', ',', '।', '?');
  $word = str_replace('@', '', $words[0][$i]);
  $lex = str_replace($bad, '', $lexs[0][$i]);
  if($lex == '#') {$lex = $word;}

  $get_def = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM hindi_dictionary WHERE lex = '$lex'");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_def)) {
    $def = $row['def'];
    }
  $find = array($word.'@'.$lex, $word.'@#');
  $replace = '<span class = "word-info" onmouseover="show_info(\''.$lex.' - '.$def.'\',\''.$word.'\');">'.$word.'</span>';

  $text = str_replace($find, $replace, $text);
  $i++;
  } while ($i < $count);

echo nl2br($text);
```

Comment: fewer DB queries will probably make the most impact, you could try refactoring so you can do a single `select * where lex in (...)` up front.

Answer (score 1):

I see that @Blorgbeard was quicker than me :)
You can change your code to call the DB only once - which should improve speed dramatically, something like:

```
...
$res = array();
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){     
    $word = str_replace('@', '', $words[0][$i]);
    $lex = str_replace($bad, '', $lexs[0][$i]);
    if($lex == '#') {$lex = $word;}
    $res[] = $lex;
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM hindi_dictionary WHERE lex in ('";
$query .= implode($res,"','") . "')";

echo $query; // something like: "SELECT * FROM hindi_dictionary WHERE lex in ('a','b','c','f')"
...
```

and continue processing the returned result-set like you originally intended - only that now you'll receive all the results once and iterate over them.

**Comment:**

It's not advisable to use `mysql_*` functions which are deprecated and vulnerable to sql-injection (see the [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)). Better use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Would it be faster to select the entire dictionary once (as I think both of you suggested) even if my dictionary contained several thousand entries?

Comment: @Travis Several thousand entries is not that big. And the answer is yes.